# How to get array from response inside search method of jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have URL which is returning `array`. I need to add or delete some keys according to requirement. I need to get that `array` inside a search function so that I can modify it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/297/). How can I get that URL.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"],  //URL response
        search:function(event,ui){        

        console.log(source)  //do some
        }
    });
```

working demo with static `array` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx7uy7b/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source option using:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source");
```

Ref (getter): https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zupxv35h/